# convergency of the sequence $x_n=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+...+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Test the convergency of the **sequence** $\{x_n\}$ , where  $$x_n=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+...+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}.$$

I think the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is convergent. As, $$|x_{2n}-x_n|=\left|(-1)^{n+2}\frac{1}{n+1}+(-1)^{n+3}\frac{1}{n+2}+...+(-1)^{2n}\frac{1}{n+n}\right|$$

$$\le\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$$

$$\le\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}\to 1 \text{ as } n\to \infty$$

As, $|x_{2n}-x_n|\not <\epsilon$ taking $\epsilon =\frac{1}{2}$ , so the sequence is NOT Cauchy and hence NOT convergent.

But I saw in a book that the sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

I could not able to understand my fallacy.

Comment: Actually it's convergent to $\ln 2$.

Comment: Consider the sequence $x_n = 1$. Of course $|x_{2n} - x_n| \le \frac n {n+1}$, but that does not contradict the convergence of $x_n$.

Comment: I also find it....When we take limit as $n\to infty$ then it becomes $\ln 2$

Comment: To help you understand why your attempt does not work, you only show that a quantity is not bigger than one. That does not prove the quantity does not tend to zero. For example, $\dfrac{1}{n^2+1} \le 1$, does that mean $\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}\not\to 0$?

Comment: You proved that $\vert x_{2n}-x_n \vert$ is LESS than $1$, not that it doesn't converge to $0$. The sequence $1/n$ is less than $1$ and converges to $0$.

Comment: Taking $\epsilon =\frac{1}{2}$ we can not say that $|x_{2n}-x_n|\not <\epsilon$

Comment: Another version of the fallacy would be bounding the sum by $+\infty$, and hence saying it doesn't converge.

Comment: How bounding the sum by $+\infty$ ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Any real number is bounded by $+\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just use the [Dirichlet test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test):
$$
\frac1n \geq \frac1{n+1},
$$
$$
  \frac1n \to 0, \, \text{as}\,\, n \to +\infty,
$$
$$
  \left|\sum_1^n (-1)^{k-1}\right| \leq 1
$$ ensuring the **convergence** of the series
$$
\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}.
$$

Comment: $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence NOT a series

Comment: $x_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k/(k+1)$

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 It is **the partial sum of a series**: so it is OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the alternating series test, which shows $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ converges. Your $x_n$ is just the $n$th partial sum of this series. By defintion of convergence of a series, $(x_n)$ converges.