# If $d(x_{n+1},x_n)<\frac{1}{n+1}$ then the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence OR not?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let , $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $d(x_{n+1},x_n)<\frac{1}{n+1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

We have, $$d(x_{n+p},x_n)\le d(x_{n+p},x_{n+p-1})+...+d(x_{n+1},x_n)$$

$$\le \frac{1}{n+p}+...+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+1}\to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty$$ for all $p=1,2,...$. So , it is Cauchy sequence.

But I found in a book that the sequence is NOT Cauchy.. I am confused.

Am I right or wrong ?

Comment: The sequence _could_ be Cauchy. $\;\;\;$ (For example, $\: \langle 1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\frac15,\ldots \rangle \:$ satisfies your assumption and is Cauchy.) $\;\;\;$ However, the sequence is not _necessarily_ Cauchy. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R$. It satisfies your condition and does not converge.

Indeed, in your argument you cannot let $n\to \infty$: The definition of a Cauchy sequence is that:

For all $\epsilon >0$, there is $N$ so that $d(x_n, x_m) <\epsilon$ whenever $n, m\ge N$.

So in your inequality

$$d(x_n, x_{n+p}) \le \frac{1}{n+p}+...+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{p} \frac{1}{n+i}$$

you should really let $p \to\infty$ (in order to consider all $m\ge n$. But then the right hand side do not converge to $0$. Indeed it goes to infinity.

Comment: OK. But where my fallacy ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: Please see the edit.

Comment: Consider the sequence $x_n=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+...+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}.$ Then , $$|x_{n+p}-x_n|=\left|(-1)^{n+2}\frac{1}{n+1}+(-1)^{n+3}\frac{1}{n+2}+...+(-1)^{n+p}\frac{1}{n+p}\right|$$ $$\le\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{n+p}= \sum_{i=1}^{p} \frac{1}{n+i}$$ . So this sequence is **NOT Cauchy** as you stated. But  the answer of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253899/convergency-of-the-sequence-x-n-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-1?noredirect=1#comment2548054_1253899) question says that this sequence is Cauchy. I am confused between these two questions...

Comment: Please tell me the different of these two questions. For the sequence , $x_n=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+...+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}$ , I found that $|x_{n+1}-x_n|=|(-1)^{n+2}\frac{1}{n+1}|=\frac{1}{n+1}\not <\frac{1}{n+1}$. So the condition does NOT hold properly...Although I think there are no mistake in calculation in the above comment .... Where my calculation looks silly ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: Your calculations are correct. But the problem is that the calculations are not good enough to tell if the sequence is Cauchy. Actually your another question is harder. You HAVE to deal with the fact that it is alternating.

Comment: My question: If a sequence is Cauchy then in any approach it will be Cauchy..So through your approach why that sequence(another question) is NOT Cauchy ?

Comment: Because if this approach is used in your other question, then you are just ignoring all the sign (all the sign are positive in this question now). THey are different question, so there is no reason that the same approach would work. @S.Panja-1729

Comment: Ok..one approach says that the sequence is Cauchy and other approach says that that is not Cauchy...So why we give more priority to be Cauchy ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 : You have misunderstood what I said. I am saying that your method is not good enough to show that the sequence is Cauchy (In both case!). In this question, I am just pointing out your mistake. I showed that the condition you gave in this question are not sufficient to show that the sequence is Cauchy **by giving a counterexample**.

Comment: As the series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent so it's sum is $\infty$. Then , $d(x_n,x_{n+p})<\infty$. From here how you can say that $d(x_n,x_{n+p}) \not \to 0$ ? I think it should be show that $d(x_n,x_{n+p})>$some positive constant. Isn't it ?